# How to transfer django form submission from one page to another?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am currently working my way through the following tutorial:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_form_processing.htm

I am brand new to django, and the previous tutorials are the only experience I have in django, so that is obviously not much to go on. When I attempt to login using the form, I get the message: **You are: Not Logged In**, However the login credentials I apply are the same I applied when I created the superuser at the beginning of the tutorial, so I feel they should be valid. Here are my files:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    user = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

**login.html**

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form name = "form" action = "{% url "login" %}"
         method = "POST" >{% csrf_token %}

         <div style = "max-width:470px;">
            <center>
               <input type = "text" style = "margin-left:20%;"
                  placeholder = "Identifiant" name = "username" />
            </center>
         </div>

         <br>

         <div style = "max-width:470px;">
            <center>
               <input type = "password" style = "margin-left:20%;"
                  placeholder = "password" name = "password" />
            </center>
         </div>

         <br>

         <div style = "max-width:470px;">
            <center>

               <button style = "border:0px; background-color:#4285F4; margin-top:8%;
                  height:35px; width:80%;margin-left:19%;" type = "submit"
                  value = "Login" >
                  <strong>Login</strong>
               </button>

            </center>
         </div>

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py** (in myapp folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView
from myapp.views import hello, viewArticle, crudops, login
from myapp.models import Dreamreal

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^hello/', hello, name = 'hello'),
    url(r'^article/(\d+)/', viewArticle, name = 'article'),
    url(r'^crudops/', crudops, name = "crudops"),
    url(r'^dreamreals/', ListView.as_view(model = Dreamreal, template_name = "dreamreal_list.html")),
    url(r'^connection/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = "login.html")),
    url(r'^login/', login, name = 'login'),


]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from myapp.models import Dreamreal
import datetime
from myapp.forms import LoginForm

def hello(request):

    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    return render(request, "hello.html", {"today":today, "days": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]})

def viewArticle(request, articleId):

    text = "Displaying article: %s " %articleId
    return HttpResponse(text)

def crudops(request):

    #Read All Entries

    objects = Dreamreal.objects.all()
    text = "Here are all the entries in the Dreamreal Database"

    for obj in objects:
        text += "<br/>" + obj.website + ", " + obj.name + "<br/>"

    return HttpResponse(text)

def login(request):

    username = "Not Logged In"

    if request.method == "POST":
        MyLoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if MyLoginForm.is_valid():
            username = MyLoginForm.cleaned_data["username"]

    else:

        MyLoginForm = LoginForm()

    return render(request, "loggedin.html", {"username": username})
```

.............................................................................

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you don't actually have any code that logs a user in. And what does all this have to do with the title of your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman all i am doing is following the tutorial I provided in the link. It states that when they click login it should say "You Are: provided username" but mine does no do that. And like I said I have like 45 minutes of django experience so I don't really know. I'm just trying to get someone to help me figure out why my code does not do what the tutorial does.

Comment: Your form has `user = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)`, while everything else, including your template, refers to `username` rather than `user`. What happens if you change `user` to `username` on your form? Maybe see if you your `MyLoginForm.is_valid()` is evaluating to `True` with a print statement for further debugging steps. I'm suspecting your form is invalid for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: @DragonBobZ thank you so much. that fixed it!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding.

Comment: I'll go ahead and post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: @DragonBobZ, this is irrelevant to this question, but do you by any chance know how to make the "Catalog" portion of the admin page show up. I'm using python 3.6, virtualenv on windows 8?

Comment: @tgrim90 unfortunately I don't know what the Catalog portion of the admin page even refers to. Logging functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field names on your form and on your template need to match. Because you have

```
<input type = "text" style = "margin-left:20%;"
 placeholder = "Identifiant" name = "username" />
```

with `name = username`, you need to make sure your form uses that field name.

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
```